# Responsive MainMenu for D7

Tags: navigation, theming

I am struggling with Drupal menu. Currently my menu is not responsive. I know how to change it to become responsive using CSS. But I am wondering If there is any module that can do this easily.

Please give any menu module if available to be responsive and adaptive to different screen sizes or suggest me if there are any simple tweaks.

Comment: what is the purpose of this question being down voted?

Comment: this one was awsome https://drupal.org/project/tinynav

Comment: You're better off using CSS, that way the end result menu will fit better with your site at the various breakpoints and in between.

Comment: I just created this one [this one](https://github.com/isramv/mobilenav) I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to answer, because it depends very much on how your menu is designed and which navigation method you're going to use.

There's a [sandbox project](http://drupal.org/sandbox/kbasarab/1791874) for the omega theme though.

Maybe this will help as well: [Complex Navigation Patterns for Responsive Design](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/complex-navigation-patterns-for-responsive-design/)